# Emergency! INO file disappeared on computer. Still on Arduino!

Tags: arduino-uno

For some reason, my Arduino program has disappeared from my computer, and it was a really long, complex program. It is currently still on my arduino, and I HAVE to get it back. Please, someone help me. Arduino UNO, Macbook Pro.

Edit: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I need the INO file back FROM MY ARDUINO.

Comment: Time to fire up your undelete program...

Comment: Lesson learned: perform backups...

Comment: Your edit changes nothing. The .ino file is not on the Arduino.

Comment: To be specific, the .ino/.pde/.cpp/.h source code is not in the Arduino.  But a working binary built from it us, which can normally be copied off and flashed to other devices.  In some cases that might help, but it's a pain to modify or reverse engineer.

Comment: Perhaps a trip around Macbook advice on undeleting files would be more fruitful? "Ask Different" maybe? Does `foremost` work on MacBook?

Comment: Don't you have a thing called time machine on a macbook pro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .ino file is lost, however, your Arduino IDE uses your `%temp%` to store immediate data.

Look in `%temp%`, folders akin to `build116193871148509168.tmp` contain build files. The original ino is not there, but I remember the `cpp` files generated by IDE should be there.

Some info about how to find the `temp` on Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607834/where-are-the-hex-files-compiled-by-arduino

Comment: I am on mac, so I went to /tmp, but no cpp files were there. Thanks for trying to help, though.

Comment: Surprisingly, when i look in my folders, the cpp is not always there. But when i searched for *<myinofilename>.cpp* it found some. Dunno when the postprocessed cpp is stored there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607834/where-are-the-hex-files-compiled-by-arduino

Answer (score 2):

Your INO file is not (ever) on your Arduino.

When you "upload your sketch" to the Arduino, it is first compiled. Your Arduino cannot interpret a sketch directly, and there are various processes which convert your sketch into machine code. This process is not practically reversible.